# Could someone help me add the missing step in this variance proof?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to prove that $Var(A_n) = \sigma^2/(na^2)$.

Given in the question is $A_n = (1/n) \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i $. Also given is $\sigma^2 = V(X_1)$.

I need to show that $P(|A_n - \mu| > a) <= \sigma^2/a^2n$.

My attempt: From Chebychev's inequality, $P(|A_n - \mu| > a) <= Var(A_n)/a^2 = \sigma^2/a^2n$

I know that the above attempt is correct but I also feel it's incomplete. I think that I could add another step to explain how we go from $Var(A_n)/a^2$ to $\sigma^2/a^2n$. Could someone help me add the missing step? Thank you.

Comment: Are you told in the question that $X_i$'s are independent?

Comment: If they are, then $$Var(A_n) = Var((1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i) = (1/n^2) \sum_{i=1}^{n} Var(X_i) = (1/n^2) \cdot n\sigma^2 = \sigma^2/n,$$ where in the second equality you use the properties of the variance and independence of $X_i$'s

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm told in the question that Xi's are random variables with the same distribution and that E(XiXj) = E(Xi)E(Xj) for i =/= j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are identically distributed with $\sigma^2 = Var(X_1) < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] = \mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j]$ for $i \neq j$, we have that

$$Var(A_n) = Var\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} 
Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right) \\[2em]
= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{1 \leq i,j\leq n} Cov(X_i,X_j) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Var(X_i) + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i \neq j} Cov(X_i,X_j).$$

But now, for $i \neq j$, $Cov(X_i,X_j) = \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] - \mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j] = 0$ by assumption. Hence, we get that

$$Var(A_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Var(X_i) = \frac{1}{n^2} (n\sigma^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$

Finally, given that $\mathbb{E}[(X_1)^2]<\infty$, using the Chebyshev's inequality, for any $a>0$, we get that

$$P(\vert A_n - \mu \vert > a) \leq \frac{Var(A_n)}{a^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{na^2},$$

where $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X_1].$